# Why the streams in C++?

Tags: c++, stream

As you all know there are libraries using streams such as `iostream` and `fstream`.

My question is:

- Why streams? Why didn't they stick with functions similar to `print`, `fgets` and so on (for example)?

They require their own operators `<<` and `>>` but all they do could be implemented in simple functions like above, also the function

```
printf("Hello World!");
```

is a lot more readable and logical to me than

```
cout << "Hello World";
```

I also think that all of those string abstractions in C++ all compile down to (less efficient) standard function calls in binary.

Comment: Efficiency is not really a concern, since 99% of the time will be spent in the same OS calls to print to the console

Comment: -1 hey boy, I suppose you are a beginner in C++ world. How can you say that it is less efficient, if you don't know? Before been critique, please, learn, and be modest.

Comment: On a related note, the Boost.Format (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/format/doc/format.html) library provides a printf-like type safe way of formatting output.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Streams have better type safety.

For instance `printf("%s", a);` can go horribly wrong if `a` is an integer. `cout << a;` doesn't have this problem.

Another issue is that streams better conform to Object Oriented design methodologies.

For instance you have a simple application that writes some output and then you want the output to go to a file instead of to the console. With C calls you'll have to replace all of the calls to `printf` to calls to `fprintf` and take care to maintain the `FILE*` along the way. With streams you just change the concrete class of the stream you're using and that's it, most of the code remains the same like so:

```
void doSomething(ostream& output)
{
   output << "this and that" << a;
}

doSomething(cout);
doSomething(ofstream("c:\file.txt"));
```

Comment: Of course, modern compilers have been extended (not in a standards compliant way) to support type checking for *printf format strings.

Comment: "With C calls you'll have to replace all of the calls to printf to calls to fprintf"  - situation is not so bad, e.g. you can do redirection of stream freopen("output.txt","w",stdout); and avoid replacement

Comment: This answer proves that the warning C4996 is useful : it detects all these old C function that could be replaced by streams. Unfortunately most people decide to disable it these days :(

Answer (score 9):

For one, it allows you to take advantage of the C++ object model to create functions that do not care whether they are writing to standard output, a file, or a network socket (if you have a network socket that derives from `ostream`). E.g.

```
void outputFoo(std::ostream& os)
{
  os << "Foo!";
}

int main()
{
  outputFoo(std::cout);

  std::ofstream outputFile("foo.txt");
  outputFoo(outputFile);

  MyNetworkStream outputSocket;
  outputFoo(outputSocket);
}
```

And similarly for input streams.

Streams also have an advantage when it comes to inputting and outputting objects. What would happen if you wanted to read in an object with `scanf`?

```
MyObject obj;
scanf("??", &obj); // What specifier to use?
```

Even if there were an appropriate specifier, how would `scanf` know how to fill in the members of the object? With C++ streams, you can overload `operator<<` and write

```
MyObject obj;
std::cin >> obj;
```

And it will work. Similarly for `std::cout << obj`, so you can write the object serialization code in one place and not have to worry about it anywhere else.

Comment: A network socket which derives from `ostream` is truely something I would like to see :)

Comment: @shoosh `boost::asio::ip::tcp::iostream`?

Answer (score 7):

C++ streams are type safe. In C, if you say:

```
double d = 1.23;
printf( "%d", d );
```

you are not guaranteed to get an error message, even though the conversion is incorrect.

You seem to be asking very basic C++ questions. Which C++ text book are you using that doesn't cover them?

Answer (score 5):

printf is not type safe for one.  The cout interface is also more generic, which allows a whole lot of things unavailable with the printf version.  One great example is that your stream operator for your types is, if you're doing it right, refering to std::ostream as the stream, not cout.  Thus you can change the destination of the output simply by using a different stream.  To do that with printf you have to do a whole lot of platform dependent overwriting of the output handles.

*I also think that all of those string abstractions in C++ all compile down to (less efficient) standard function calls in binary.*

Think all you want.  Until you actually test your assumption your opinion won't hold much weight.  Furthermore you need to consider the loss of abstraction, something that is usually a whole lot more important in modern software development.

Answer (score 3):

Besides being type safe and polymorphic, streams are more portable. On some systems printf with a long requires "%d" and on some systems it requires "%ld".

Comment: Compliance always requires `%ld`, but the `l` does nothing on some platforms.

Comment: I've changed lots of complicated, crazy code to work around this to use streams without ever realizing that!

Comment: +1 one day I was lost a for long time until I used debugger for watching

Answer (score 2):

Streams can be chained together

```
cout << "hello" << " " << "world"
```

Comment: So could be methods: out.print("hello").print(" ").print("world")

Comment: `std::cout.operator<<("hello").operator<<(" ").operator<<("world");`

Answer (score 2):

Another benefit of streams is that they were made to be extendable.  With streams, you can have your user defined classes work just like built in types:

```
class foo { ... };

ostream &operator<<(ostream &ostr, const foo &f)
{
    ostr << ... how you want to print a foo ...;
    return ostr;
}
```

And now you can print a foo just like anything else:

```
int n = ...
foo f = ...

cout << n << ": " << f << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

C++ IOStreams *are* ridiculously inefficient (in most implementations I know of). Often, that is not a concern, but *when* it is, the library is basically useless. It's also a good point that the syntax is unintuitive (and very, very verbose). The library is complex and needlessly hard to extend. It's not very flexible either. When contrasted against something like the STL, IOStreams really looks like a bad dream. But it's here, and we're stuck with it.

The reason it's here, and the reason it looks like it does, is that it was developed earlier, before C++ was a mature language. Before we had decades of experience telling us what is, and is not, good library design. Before anyone really knew what the options were.

C++ needed an I/O library that was *better* than C's. And in some important ways, C++ IOStreams *are* better. They're type-safe and extensible as others have mentioned. By implementing a single operator, I can print out a user-defined class. That couldn't be done with `printf`. I also don't have to worry about getting format specifiers wrong and printing out garbage because of a lack of type safety.

Those things *needed* to be fixed. And hey, in the early days, virtual functions and operator overloading were *the shit*. It looked cool. Of course libraries wanted to use those features.

The IOStreams library is a compromise between:

- something safer and more extensible than C's `stdio.h`
- something efficient
- something well-designed and intuitive
- a library that actually *existed* at the time when C++ was being standardized. (they had to add *something*, so they had to choose between the candidates that actually existed at the time.)

The library doesn't achieve all of these, and I believe that today, with our decades of experience with the language, we could have designed a far better library. But back in the mid-90's, when they were looking for an I/O library to add, this was the best they could find.

Answer (score 1):

The stream like syntax with `operator<<` and `operator>>` allows nice concatenation.

```
printf("%d%d%d%d%d", a, b, c, d, e);
```

vs

```
cout << a << b << c << d << e;
```

Moreover in the first approach one must always think about the type, while in the stream approach, the type must not be specified.

Answer (score 1):

Actually

```
cout << "Test: " << test << endl;
```

seems a lot more intuitive to me than

```
printf("Test: %d\n", test);
```

If you'd never seem a printf before, there's no way you're going to know what that does.

In either case,

```
print "Test: " + test
```

(in several languages, <strike>including Python</strike> :( ) makes *a lot* more sense :)

Comment: Python has `print "Test: %d" % test` too, and it is very necessary for more complicated formatting.

Comment: @UncleBens: True, and it's very unfortunate they chose to use C-style format-strings, *especially* requiring the typing for a dynamic language...

Comment: If you never seen C++ streams before, its even worse: you think you are performing some mad bit shifting!

Comment: @BlueRaja The Green Unicorn: i think that, for example, printf("%-04d", test) is more readable than C++ equivalent.

Comment: You can use the `%s` specifier for any type in Python. On the other hand `print "Test: " + test` doesn't appear to work if test is an integer.

Comment: @el.pescado: That will only confuse those who have written in C but not C++.  Making a language-design decision simply because *"we don't want to confuse users coming from another language"* is a great way to duplicate the mistakes of other languages (see Java's and C#'s godawful `switch` blocks, for example)

Answer (score 1):

C++ lets you use printf, by the way.  So if you like that, go ahead and use it.

Streams are used for a lot more than writing output to the console.  They're a general purpose data buffering solution that can be applied to everything from screen output to file handling to network traffic and input device interfaces.  Your stuff can write to (or read from) streams without caring where that data is actually going to go.

Say you have a complex object that you want to be able to write to the output console, to a log file, and into a debugging window popup.  Are you going to write three functions that do almost the exact same thing, or are you going to write one function to which you pass an(y) output stream?

Answer (score 0):

I still use printf, mainly because it's easy to control the output format.

To me, type safety is not a main benefit here because it can be easily caught by test, given the fact that a console based program is far more easily to test with than UI based or web based applications. If you don't do test, more serious bugs can get over the compile time check any way.

I also don't agree with another reason that claims stream is more flexible due to interchangeability. It's equivalent to recommend using fprintf(fout,...) for interchangeability. If you need to redirect the output, use pipe. If you are in a library, why don't you just return a string and let the caller decide where it goes?

Comment: Use a pipe - not everything is a command like application. Return a string - not very efficient.

Comment: shoosh, just from curiosity, how can you return a string  in C from from function? I mean if it was allocated there  as (static char *mystring), you'd return only a pointer. if you mean string from STL then you return only object that represents a string, string is held somewhere else - no looses in effectiveness

Answer (score 0):

`stringstream` is safer than `snprintf`/`sscanf` because it entirely avoids the possibility of buffer overflow (even "graceful failures").

Answer (score 0):

Streams work with templates, whereas `printf/scanf` don't.